# Fisher test more than 2 groups

Tags: r, statistics, stata

Major Edit:
I decided to rewrite this question since my original was poorly put. I will leave the original question below to maintain a record. Basically, I need to do Fisher's Test on tables as big as 4 x 5 with around 200 observations. It turns out that this is often a major computational challenge as explained [here](http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/stats/contingency.problem.html) (I think, I can't follow it completely). As I use both R and Stata I will frame the question for both with some made-up data.

Stata:

```
    tabi 1 13 3 27 46 \ 25 0 2 5 3 \ 22 2 0 3 0 \ 19 34 3 8 1 , exact(10)
```

You can increase `exact()` to 1000 max (but it will take maybe a day before returning an error).

R:

```
    Job <- matrix(c(1,13,3,27,46, 25,0,2,5,3, 22,2,0,3,0, 19,34,3,8,1), 4, 5,
         dimnames = list(income = c("< 15k", "15-25k", "25-40k", ">40k"),
         satisfaction = c("VeryD", "LittleD", "ModerateS", "VeryS", "exstatic")))
    fisher.test(Job)
```

For me, at least, it errors out on both programs. So the question is how to do this calculation on either Stata or R?

Original Question:
I have Stata and R to play with.
I have a dataset with various categorical variables, some of which have multiple categories.
Therefore I'd like to do Fisher's exact test with more than 2 x 2 categories
i.e. apply Fisher's to a 2 x 6 table or a 4 x 4 table.

Can this be done with either R or Stata ?

Edit: whilst this can be done in Stata - it will not work for my dataset as I have too many categories. Stata goes through endless iterations and even being left for a day or more does not produce a solution.

My question is really -  can R do this, and can it do it quickly ?

Comment: How big is your table remains a key detail.

Comment: Yes you are correct - just checking that now. n = 191, category 1 has 4 divisons, category 2 has 5. This is one that absolutely would not work for me. After about a day and a half it returned an error saying too many values

Comment: This gets more puzzling. I see no reason why that strains Stata. Can you post the data?

Comment: Ah...I can't really (confidentiality reasons). My understanding is that it is just a raw processing power thingy - each time you add a category you exponentially increase the number of possible distributions of the observations and even at 4 x 5 and n = 191 its heavy duty calcutation

Comment: I got instantaneous response to `tabi 2 2 2 2 2 \ 13 13 13 13 13 \ 4  4 4 4 4 \ 20 20 20 20 20 , exact`. That's not a proof but it's a counterexample to the idea that 4 x 5 (with n about 200) tables are necessarily problematic. I wonder if your memory request makes things worse.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that later this evening for my data. Thanks Nick I will let you know how it goes. Again apologies for a poor question

Comment: @Nick Cox ok tabi again doesn't work with my data. The reason yours worked is because you put similar numbers in all the rows - I don't fully understand it but this somehow makes the problem easier to solve. Here try it with this made up data: 'tabi 1 13 3 27 46 \ 25 0 2 5 3 \ 22 2 0 3 0 \ 19 34 3 8 1 , exact(100)' There is an explanation here as to why this is a difficult problem but I don't fully understand it:[link](http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/stats/exact.html)

Answer (score 5):

Have you studied the documentation of R function `fisher.test`? Quoting from `help("fisher.test")`:

> For 2 by 2 cases, p-values are obtained directly using the (central or
>   non-central) hypergeometric distribution. Otherwise, computations are
>   based on a C version of the FORTRAN subroutine FEXACT which implements
>   the network developed by Mehta and Patel (1986) and improved by
>   Clarkson, Fan and Joe (1993).

This is an example given in the documentation:

```
Job <- matrix(c(1,2,1,0, 3,3,6,1, 10,10,14,9, 6,7,12,11), 4, 4,
              dimnames = list(income = c("< 15k", "15-25k", "25-40k", "> 40k"),
                              satisfaction = c("VeryD", "LittleD", "ModerateS", "VeryS")))
fisher.test(Job)

# Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data
# 
# data:  Job
# p-value = 0.7827
# alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Comment: Thanks Roland. Yes I saw that but I didn't really understand it (I'm have no experience of matrixes, or c versions of Fortan subroutines). I must apologise for my original question which was fired form the hip without me thinking it out as this issue came up again today to haunt me. Previously when I treid doing my multicategory table in stata, stata could not handle the number of categories. I guess what I'm wondering is will R be any better (same CPU after all)

Comment: You don't need experience with C versions of Fortran subroutines. It's all inside R functions. Of course, you should read a basic introduction to R before using it. A matrix is a really basic data structure in R. Since `fisher.test` uses C code internally it should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Even so I've had no cause to use matrices in R previously

Comment: Well, you don't need a matrix. Read the documentation. It allows an alternative way of passing input data to the function.

Comment: Thanks Roland I'll have a look at it

Comment: I've just tested. If the number of factor levels gets big, the function returns errors informing you that the problem size is too big. I suspect you'll need a different algorithm.

Comment: Oh thanks Roland you got there quicker than I did - yes this is what I was afraid of. Many thanks

Comment: So why do you need exact p-values? In R you could run a MC-simulation easily (if certain conditions are satisfied) using `fisher.test(x, y, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B=1e7)`. That should be sufficiently precise for most applications.

Comment: -good question. I don't really but I need exact p values because reviewers want them, and, for some reason, noone seems to know this is a hard problem once you go beyond 2 x 2. Thanks for the suggestion - I could not get it to work. The simulate thingy just seems to divide 1 by the value of B - try it with different B's. Her is the R version of the Stata made up data: 'Job <- matrix(c(1,13,3,27,46, 25,0,2,5,3, 22,2,0,3,0, 19,34,3,8,1), 4, 5, dimnames = list(income = c("< 15k", "15-25k", "25-40k", "> 40k"), satisfaction = c("VeryD", "LittleD", "ModerateS", "VeryS", "exstatic")))'

Comment: @user2498193 I think your p-value is just extremely small.

Answer (score 3):

As far as Stata is concerned, your original statement was totally incorrect. `search fisher` leads quickly to `help tabulate twoway` and

- the help for the `exact` option explains that it may be applied to *r* x
      *c* as well as to 2 x 2 tables
- the very first example in the same place of Fisher's exact test underlines that Stata is not limited to 2 x 2 tables.

It's a minimal expectation anywhere on this site that you try to read basic documentation. Please!

Comment: Sorry, I oversimplified - it has been out of my head for a while and just came up again today. I'll edit the question to correct. I have searched and read basic documentation extensively on this in the past I hasten to add yet could not solve my problem

Comment: Your statement was not even an oversimplification! I've given you hints on how to find things. `search` with keywords is one way to start. http://www.stata.com/manuals13/i.pdf is a searchable, accessible summary of the documentation and you can get to where I got in a few keystrokes. You just need "Fisher" as a start.

Comment: I have been down this road extensively. Stata cannot do what I need.
Just opened up my script from before.
Even this crashed after about 30 hours on me:

        tab categorical1 categorical2, exact(1000)

Comment: I believe you, but you wasted people's time, yours too, in not asking your real question.

Comment: I apologise again.
Honestly - it is months since I had looked at it and this was the short form my brain remembered until you prompted me to think about it mroe. I will do more thinking before posting next time. And thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Sure, and thanks for the apology, but please consider your questions more carefully in future.